# Memory leak in directory_iterator of boost filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2015, boost-filesystem

I am using the boost filesystem to list all files and directories of a given path. The simple code for it looks like following:

```
directory_iterator iterator(path("."));
for(; iterator != directory_iterator(); ++iterator) {
    cout << iterator->path().filename() << endl;
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` reports the following memory leaks:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{470} normal block at 0x03CEDED8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <,       > 2C FD D1 00 00 00 00 00 
{394} normal block at 0x03CEE370, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > 04 FD D1 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

When commenting out the for loop the leaks persist, so the `directory_iterator` must be somehow causing them. As far as i know you don't need to delete any iterators, so what could be the problem here?

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 with boost_1_60_0.

Comment: The VS memory leak detection stuff often results in false positives.  Try a real memory profiler to see if there's even a leak at all.

Comment: That was the problem. I installed visual leak detector and it didn't report any leaks.

Comment: Well, there you go.  If you have any static variables that could be it.  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks reports what memory was allocated but not removed.  It doesn't track whether it's still accessible by the program.  So if a global or static allocated memory it often reports that memory as "leaked" when it really isn't.  Real memory profilers track differently and so are better at this...but you'll still sometimes get false positives.

If you are really worried about it, check out your globals and such.  If any are 'newed' then you could try putting that in a smart pointer to be rid of the bitching.